# Maximum absolute deviation

Tags: statistics, image-processing

Let $I$, $J$ be two gray scale images. How will I be able to interpret the maximum absolute deviation between the histograms of these images?

Comment: Dear Juan, you really need to work on your mastery of the English language if you want useful comments. Many of your questions are hard to understand, and I, for one, do not understand what you want from us in this question. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Thank by your feedback, I edit my question.